# How to install FFMPEG for your discord bot?

Tags: ffmpeg, discord.js

I want to make my discord bot to play music , but i keep getting "FFMPEG not found" error.

My bot is mostly made out of pings so i won't upload that part. The music code should be this one.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
var bm = message.content.toLowerCase()

bot.on('message',(message) => {

     if (bm == "pray") {
    var VC = message.member.voiceChannel;
    if (!VC)
        return message.reply("You are not in the church my son.")
VC.join()
    .then(connection => {
        const dispatcher = connection.playFile('d:/mp3.MP3');
        dispatcher.on("end", end => {VC.leave()});
    })
    .catch(console.error); )
```

P.S. : I know that i should import the FFMPEG somehow because i have it downloaded already. But i don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer here , at http://blog.gregzaal.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/ . Here you can see how to add the FFMPEG to download , unzip , path and use it.

Answer (score 0):

You should install all ffmpeg-related modules from NPM, and then define it (like, `const ffmpeg = require("ffmpeg-extra")`.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> **Watch**: [How to set Environment variables in Windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEroNNzqlF4).
>   
>   This is required to understand the **HowTo** below.

## Install FFmpeg

- Download the binaries from zeranoe.
- Extract it and copy the `bin` folder contents.
- Create a directory named `ffmpeg_bins` in `C:` drive.
- Add it to path by clicking **Browse Folder**.

**Congratulations,** You've just learned to install FFmpeg in Windows OS.